# change line stretch in markdown to pdf

Tags: r, latex, markdown, pandoc

in a R markdown doc knitting to PDF, can I have different line stretches in a single document? if yes, how? in the example below, I've set the line stretch to 1.5 in the YAML, but 1/2 way through I want to change to 1.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "today"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    number_sections: no
linestretch: 1.5
---

this text has a line stretch of 1.5

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 


now the text below should have no line stretch:

some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text
```

Comment: I think you'd have to use raw LaTeX commands inside your markdown body text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\setstretch{}`

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "today"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    number_sections: no
linestretch: 1.5
---

this text has a line stretch of 1.5

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 


now the text below should have no line stretch:

\setstretch{1}
some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text some tigther text
```